# C++ adding matrices, program has stopped working

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, vector, crash

Here is my code, the program crashes but there is no error.
The matrixPrinter worked perfectly when I tested it on the declared matrices

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix1 = {
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3}
    };

std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix2 = {
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3}
    };

std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrixAdder(std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrixA , std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrixB )
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > result;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < matrixA.size(); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < matrixB.size(); j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void matrixPrinter(std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < matrix.size() ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << '|';
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < matrix[i].size() ; j++)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '|';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    matrixPrinter(matrixAdder(matrix1, matrix2));
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: in `matrixAdder` the loop limits are wrong

Comment: ...however with A and B being square and of same size this should actually not cause a crash. Is this really the code that crashes? Or did you change the dimnesions of the matrices?

Comment: Might be a good idea to pass by const reference to the print method, especially if the matrices can get bigger than 3by3 `matrixPrinter(const std::vector< std::vector<int> >& matrix)` .

Comment: yes it is, I just copypasted it.

Comment: ups overlooked it, your `result` matrix is of size 0x0 unless you resize it. All explained in the answer to the dupe ;)

Comment: thanks for answer George, but this didn't help

Comment: you are trying to access elements in `result` that dont exist yet

Comment: @cold_cash It's wasn't an answer, just a suggestion :p As is, the matrix is copied every time it's printed and when matrix adder is called (assuming it's fixed), matrix a and b are both copied as well as the result.